# How to fetch multitable records with eager loading Laravel5.2

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, eager-loading

I have three tables (users,posts,and favourites).
How do i get all the posts with laravel eloquent along with favourite posts and the name of the person who marked it as favourite.

**Users**
  id
  name
  email

**Posts**
  id
  name

**Favourites**
  id
  user_id
  post_id

This is what i am trying to do in controller but unabe to iterate it in view.

$posts = Post::with('favourites','users')->take(10)->get();

Please have a look into this [link](http://laravel.io/bin/W4mnz) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

In your view file try

```
@forech($posts as $post)

    @foreach($post->favourites as $favourite)

           //do your staff here like

           {{ $favourite->users->name }}
    @endforeach
@endforech
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,But you don't think this will result into N+1problem?

Comment: Ok then you can eager load users with favourites like this "favourite.users" in your Post::with("favourite.users","otherRelations")

Comment: Yes,its better one,i am having a problem now.I want only logged in user to view his liked posts,at the moment the nested loop fetches all the users likes ,How to tackle this.

Comment: Visit https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads this will help you to understand eager loading constraints. In your case try Post::with(['favourite'=>function($query){ return $query->with(['users'=>function($q){ return $q->where(conditions goes here or you can use multiple where() )} ]) },'users'])->take(10)->get();